# Unable to see the Knowledge and Article Management tab in salesforce why?

Tags: knowledge

I want to enable the Knowledge and Article Management. This is done by navigating to `My Settings` --> `Personal` --> `Advanced User Details`.

In doing so I don't see the `Knowledge` tab. I also don't see the `Article Management` tab. Why?

[image: Advanced User Details]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Salesforce Knowledge is enabled, the following permissions are required to be able to configure Knowledge:

**"Manage Salesforce Knowledge"** - Profile Permission

You can find the "Manage Salesforce Knowledge" one of two ways:

- If you do not have the "Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface" enabled

  2. Click Setup | Manage Users | Profiles
  3. Click on the Profile
  4. Scroll down to the Administrative Permissions section
  5. Select Manage Salesforce Knowledge
- If you have the "Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface" enabled

  1. Click Setup | Manage Users | Profiles
  2. Click on the Profile
  3. Click on App Permissions
  4. In the Knowledge Management section, select Manage Salesforce Knowledge
     "Knowledge User" - User Record Permission
     The "Knowledge User" permission is also required for all users who will be using Knowledge.

You also need to make sure that the Tabs are visible as necessary:

1. From Setup, enter Profiles in the Quick Find box, then select Profiles.
2. Select a User profile.
3. Click Edit.
4. Set the visibility of the necessary tabs to Default On.
5. Click Save.

[image]

Link for reference::https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005402&type=1

Answer (score 1):

To enable Salesforce Knowledge, from Setup, enter Knowledge in the Quick Find box, then select Knowledge Settings. Confirm that you want to enable Salesforce Knowledge and click Enable Knowledge. If your org doesn't have an article type, a default article type is created.

please find the below link for creating Article Type:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_templates_create.htm&type=0

Set up the knowledge settings like below: -
[image]

see the below screenshot : -

[image]

you can create article type here.

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled Salesforce Knowledge, and you're sure all permissions are configured correctly then there may be another simple reason for it to seemingly not work: If you previously had the Content Management Workspace open before you enabled these settings, you will need to refresh the page. This was my case as I was completing the *Add Knowledge to the Community Using Topics* module in Trailhead.